# S3 Access Across Regions VPC/Peering - Latency reduction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

I need to be able to retrieve an S3 object residing in Australia S3 Storage from London EC2 and minimise latency.

On the London EC2 instance, I set the RegionEndpoint on the S3Client to ApSouthEast2 and acquire it.

The issue I am facing is that the it takes far too long to retrieve even small files (10kb file - 1.2s+). I have Peering setup on the server also so I can ping EC2 instances in ApSouthEast2 from London and my round trips are all 0ms.

However, when retrieving data from S3 it is a different story. How can I allow the s3 bucket to be available "internally" (vpc endpoints and via existing peering??) as I am assuming traversal over WAN is creating this huge lag.

It must be stressed that any changes I make will still require the S3 bucket to be available in its current state as this is a production system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is impossible to have 0ms latency between Europe and Australia. Something to do with the speed of light. See: [Ping time between London and Sydney - WonderNetwork](https://wondernetwork.com/pings/London/Sydney)

I would recommend you try to connect to S3 *directly* (rather than via VPC Peering) and see whether the speed is any better.

Then, try connecting via [Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration.html) and see if it is any better. Connections are routed via the AWS network.

Worst case, you could always **replicate the bucket** to the London region so that objects are copied soon after they are created. You can then access the objects locally.

Comment: Thanks John - Yes I obviously stuffed up the pings. I have enabled Transfer Acceleration on both ends up/down. The performance increase is substantial and that is probably an understatement. It seems though, If I don't make a request within a few minutes of the first - it's like it loses it's "path" and the performance blows out (to the point where it is slower than non-accelerated requests). Any ideas on how to resolve this or what causes this?

Comment: Transfer acceleration significantly reduced  transit time in 90%+ cases. The other 10% seem to "lose" their path, or cache, or something I'm not aware of and produce a slower retrieval than the standard method seemingly.